# Registration Plugin - Recaptcha integration

Tags: security

Good Day Everyone,

I'm currently writing a new plugin for Registration, I intend to actually share that Registration Plugin, but I would like to integrate reCaptcha into it.

From what I understood reCaptcha is actually website related; So if I want to integrate it in my plugin I would need to ask the user/admin of the websites to actually enter their website key to "activate" it?

Or did I understood that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin users will need to register their site at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin to use the reCAPTCHA API. Once registered, users will need to provide you with their Site Key and Secret Key.

The Site Key allows you to display the reCAPTCHA on your Registration form.  The Secret Key is used to confirm the reCAPTCHA field input.

Comment: Exactly what I needed confirmed! Finally someone nice around here ;-)

Comment: @pSyToR Glad my answer helped.